# Как сделать генерацию таблицы в цикле вот так?

Tags: php, html

Создаю таблицу вот так:

```
<?php
$dir = "./";
$name = scandir($dir);
        echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=12 cellpadding=12>";

for($i=2; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
    if ($name[$i] !="index.php") {      

     if($i%2 == 0){ 
        echo "<tr align=\"center\"><td><a href='".$dir.$name[$i]."'>".$name[$i]."</a></td>"; 
    } else { 
        echo "<td><a href='".$dir.$name[$i]."'>".$name[$i]."</a></td></tr>";  
    }

    }
}
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

1 2

3 4

5 6

....

Как сделать, чтобы таблица создавалась в четыре колонки?

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

8 9 10 11

....

Ну и примерчик в три колонки не помешает (собираюсь адаптировать вывод под разрешение экрана) вот так:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

....

СПАСИБО!

Comment: array_chunk вам в помощь

Comment: `array_chunk()`не подойдет, потому что надо игнорировать 3 записи.

Comment: А ещё можно избежать `'.'` и `'..'` если заменить $dir = "./"; $name = scandir($dir); на $array_names = glob('*.txt'); Вместо расширения `*.txt` подставить необходимое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что таким способом Вы выводите на экран содержимое некой папки... И проблема заключается в том, что счетчик Вы начинаете сразу со второй позиции...

Вам надо изменить цикл.

```
$i = 0;
$cols = 2; // кол-во колонок
echo '<table>';
foreach($name as $file) {
    if ($file !="index.php") {      
        if($i%$cols == 0){ 
            if ($i>0) echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr align=\"center\">"; 
        }
         echo "<td><a href='".$dir.$file."'>".$file."</a></td>";  
    }
    $i++;
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: вы очень часто закрываете `</tr>`

Comment: @Saidolim увидел... уже исправил :)

Comment: Спасибо, взял Вашу реализацию - работает на ура и добавил удаление точек из первого примера!

Comment: последнюю строку не закроет, пустые ячейки в последней строке не добьёт.

Comment: @Sergiks ну если на то пошло, то и таблицу не откроет :):):):) - Исправлено

Answer (score 2):

На всё, что повторяется, стоит сделать по циклу: на строки и на ячейки тоже:

```
$cols = 3;   // сколько колонок
$total = 14; // всего ячеек (0..13)

echo "<table>";
for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i += $cols) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j = $i; $j < $i + $cols; $j++) {
        if( $j < $total) {
            echo "<td>" . $j . "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td> - </td>"; // значения кончились
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/4aN2uw)

---

**P.S.** легко избавиться от двух первых ненужных элементов на *nix'ах с одной и двумя точками:

```
$name = array_diff( scandir( $dir), array( '.', '..'));
```

**P.P.S.** сделать фон строк чередующимся через строчку можно таким CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd)  {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: Спасибо работает!

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
<?php
$dir = "./";
$name = scandir($dir);

echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=12 cellpadding=12>";

$chisloKolonok = 3;
$propustitElementi = 2;
$k = 0;

for($i=$propustitElementi; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
   $k++; 
    if ($name[$i] !="index.php") {      

     if($k % $chisloKolonok == 1){ 
        echo "<tr align=\"center\">"; 
    } else if($k % $chisloKolonok == 0){ 
        echo "</tr>"; 
    }

    echo "<td><a href='".$dir.$name[$i]."'>".$name[$i]."</a></td>";  
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Не работает Ваш пример!